# Batch going into all subdirectories containing a Makefile and executing make there; does not work with space in path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a batch script under Windows 10 that goes into all subdirectories containing a file named "Makefile" and executes the command "make" there. The make command is in my path.

I have the following script that fails if the path contains a space:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s Makefile') do (
  cd "%%~pi"
  make
  if errorlevel 1 exit /b %errorlevel%
  cd ..
)
```

If the path of the directory where I start the script contains a space, the *"%%~pi"*, although quoted, seems to cut the subdirectories starting with the one containing a space.

**Example:**

Assuming there is a file "C:\Users\Username\Documents\space dir\src\Makefile"

When executing above batchscript from dir "space dir", it tries to execute the make command in dir "C:\Users\Username\Documents\space dir", forgetting the "src"

How can I fix this problem or what would be an alternative batch script that does the job?

Comment: Instead of `for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s Makefile') do (`, use `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s /a:-d "makefile"') do (`, then instead of `cd "%%~pi"` and `cd ..`, use `pushd "%%~i"`, and `popd` respectively. I would also question whether you want  to `exit` on any error, which would prevent any other `make` commands, should there be multiple `makefile`s within the tree.

Comment: Awesome, this approach works. However, the `%%i` variable still goes through filenames, so it has to be `pushd "%%~pi` instead of  `pushd "%%~i"`. Would you provide your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo, I intended to use `pushd "%%~dpi"`, _(there is rarely a need to miss the `d`)_. Feel free to self answer if you think that it would be useful to future readers. For me, I don't need the points, and IMO, your solution is simply that you've not implemented the information output when entering the commands help option, `for /?`.

Comment: `if errorlevel 1 exit /b %errorlevel%` won't act as expected as `%errorlevel%` will be replaced by its value at the time the `for` is parsed. Since you have enabled delayedexpansion, use `if errorlevel 1 exit /b !errorlevel!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by Compo and Magoo, I could assemble the following working solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s /a:-d "Makefile"') do (
  pushd "%%~dpi"
  make
  if errorlevel 1 exit /b !errorlevel!
  popd
)
```

Explanation of the improvements:

The most important fix is adding the `"delims="` to the `for` loop. This keeps the `for` loop from parsing lines into tokens, thus avoiding the split caused by spaces in the path.

The added option `/a:-d` keeps the `dir` command from listing a path where Makefile is a directory name instead of a filename.

The use of `pushd` and `popd` is an elegant and more safe way to visit the subdirectories and it keeps the original working dir when the script ends.

The `!errorlevel!` (instead of `%errorlevel%`) ensures the expansion of the variable at the correct time.